# Angular - How to populate the empty input field when the dropdrown is selected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-select

I'm trying to create the DropdownBox that will populate input fields once I selected the value,

```
{ name:'Arnold', item:'Laptop' }
```

The dropdown contains the `Name` once I selected "Arnold" it will populate the other empty textbox with "Laptop". How do achieve that?

So far this is what I code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-qzg1ea

Comment: From your link, the dropdown didn't populate any option. I guess there is a bug. While will be great if you can post a minimal Reproducible Example (code) in the question. Link is fragile and your question may not be useful for the future readers if the link is broken. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the issue that I mentioned in the comment.

Actually, you are almost near to the answer.

```
<mat-select
    (selectionChange)="selectedType($event)"
    formControlName="name"
    style="width:200px"
  >
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.name">
    {{ item.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

You need the [`selectionChange`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) event to trigger when the dropdown is selected/changed.

```
selectionChange: EventEmitter<C>
```

> Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.

In the `selectedType` method, find the selected item from the `items` array. If the item is found, use `.patchValue()` to patch the value to `item` control.

```js
items = ELEMENT_DATA;

selectedType(trigger: MatSelectChange) {
  ...

  const selectedItem = this.item.find((x) => x.name == trigger.value);
  if (selectedItem) this.fg.controls.item.patchValue(selectedItem.item);
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-nyrk3j?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: What if i have DTO that will subscribe?  like this one getItem(){
      this.ItemSvc.getItemlist(true).subscribe((response: DTO) => {
      this.propertyItemObject = response;
      this.propertyItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.propertyItemObject.items));
    })
  }

which im using services

Comment: Can you share the DTO class? Assume the response (DTO type) is `{name:'Arnold',item:'Laptop'}`. Then to get the item should be `const item = response.item;`

Comment: getItem(){ this.ItemSvc.getItemlist(true).subscribe((response: DTO) => { this.propertyItemObject = response; this.propertyItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.propertyItemObject.items)); }) }

  selectedItem(trigger:MatSelectChange){
   this.propertyItemObject = trigger.value;

   const selectedItem = this.propertyItemObject.ItemName.find((x) => x.propertyNo == trigger.value);
   if(selectedItem) this.form.patchValue(selectedItem.ItemName)
  }

id: 147, appNo: '.', propertyNo: '125', ItemName: 'MULTI-PURPOSE COPY PAPER 70GSM A4'}